# How to Use a SecureFile in an Azure DevOps variable group?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-cloud-services, azure-security

I have a Secure File called my-certificate.p12 in my azure devops pipeline library. It has given pipeline permissions to my pipeline my-azure-pipeline. Then I added a pipeline variable to the my-azure-pipeline pipeline called MY_CERTIFICATE which has my-certificate.p12 as its value. I reference this certificate like so in my .yaml file:

```
certSecureFile: $(MY_CERTIFICATE)
```

this is working fine!

However I've started to try and use a variable group across multiple pipelines with some common fields, like this certificate. When I created a new variable group, my-variable-group, and add a field called MY_CERTIFICATE which has a value of my-certificate.p12 and use this variable group like so in my .yaml file:

```
variables:
      - group: my-variable-group
# still using this to reference it: $(MY_CERTIFICATE)
```

I run into an issue where it says the file could not be used because it is not authorized to be used... How can I get my variable group to have access to the Secure File so I can use it like this and why does it work when used directly as a pipeline variable and not within a variable group?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked "Pipeline permissions" section?

Take a look at "How do I authorize a secure file for use in a specific pipeline?" in FAQ section
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/secure-files?view=azure-devops#faq

Comment: yes I have already added all of my pipelines to the allowed list of pipelines the secure file can be used in unfortunately